# A typical inequality: $\frac{8}{27}\leq\frac{(x^2+yz)(y^2+zx)(z^2+xy)}{(xy+yz+zx)^3}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> For $x, y, z\in (0, \infty)$ prove that: $$\frac{8}{27}\leq\frac{(x^2+yz)(y^2+zx)(z^2+xy)}{(xy+yz+zx)^3}.$$

My attempts to apply media inequality or other inequalities have been unsuccessful. In desperation I did the calculations and I have a rather complicated question question that I could not write as the sum of squares:

$$ 0\leq 6x^2y^2z^2 +19(x^3y^3+y^3z^3+z^3x^3)+27(x^4yz+xy^4z+xyz^4)-24(x^3y^2z+x^3yz^2+x^2y^3z+xy^3z^2+x^2yz^3+xy^2z^3).$$
Thanks for any ideas that might help me clarify the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution based on what you have already obtained and AM-GM:

It is easy to check that;
$$x^2y^2z^2+x^4yz+x^3y^3 \geq3x^3y^2z.$$
So we need to show that;
$$17(x^3y^3+x^3z^3+z^3y^3)+25(x^4yz+xy^4z+xyz^4)\geq21(x^3y^2z+x^3yz^2+x^2y^3z+x^2yz^3+xy^3z^2+xy^2z^3).$$

Now realize that we simply get;
$$x^3y^3+x^3y^3+x^3y^3+x^4yz+x^4yz+xyz^4\geq6x^3y^2z,$$

by adding all the similar inequalities together, we will have;
$$(x^3y^3+x^3z^3+z^3y^3)+(x^4yz+xy^4z+xyz^4)\geq(x^3y^2z+x^3yz^2+x^2y^3z+x^2yz^3+xy^3z^2+xy^2z^3).$$
Hence, it is just needed to prove that;
$$8(x^4yz+xy^4z+xyz^4)\geq4(x^3y^2z+x^3yz^2+x^2y^3z+x^2yz^3+xy^3z^2+xy^2z^3).$$
Equivalently, we should show that;
$$2xyz(x^3+y^3+z^3)\geq xyz(xy(x+y)+xz(x+z)+yz(y+z)).$$
And this is almost obvious since $x^3+y^3\geq xy(x+y).$

Comment: Note that your "so we need to show that" is just Muirhead - $M(4,1,1) \geq M(3, 2, 1)$ and $M(3, 3, 0) ) \geq M(3, 2, 1)$ -  so this solution is essentially a two-liner. ( I was going to post that since it was much simplier/immediate the these solution, then realized it was yours.)

Comment: @CalvinLin Hello. Yes. you are right. Majorization didn't strike me when writing the solution at all.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following inequalities:

(1) Schur's inequality times $2xyz$:

$$xyz(x(x-y)(x-z)+y(y-z)(y-x)+z(z-x)(z-y))\ge 0$$

That is

$$2(x^4yz+y^4zx+z^4xy)+6x^2y^2z^2\ge 2(x^3y^2z+x^3yz^2+x^2y^3z+xy^3z^2+x^2yz^3+xy^2z^3)$$

(2) $12.5$ times $x^3+y^3-x^2y-xy^2\ge 0$: that is $12.5\sum_{cyc}xyz(x^3+y^3-x^2y-xy^2)\ge 0$. That is,
$$25(x^4yz+y^4zx+z^4xy)\ge 12.5(x^3y^2z+x^3yz^2+x^2y^3z+xy^3z^2+x^2yz^3+xy^2z^3)$$

(3) $9.5$ times $x^3+y^3-x^2y-xy^2\ge 0$: that is $9.5\sum_{cyc}(xy)^3+(yz)^3-(xy)(yz)^2-(xy)^2(yz)\ge 0$. That is,

$$19(x^3y^3+y^3z^3+z^3x^3)\ge 9.5(x^3y^2z+x^3yz^2+x^2y^3z+xy^3z^2+x^2yz^3+xy^2z^3)$$

Comment: Two questions: 1) when you add the three inequalities, how is the result connected to the question ? 2) What is your method for finding out your path ? Do you use a general/specialized software ?

Comment: (1) When you add those three, this is exactly the degree-6 polynomial form of OP's inequality. (2) I have not used software or something. Notice that the only trouble of that inequality is to deal with $x^2y^2z^2$ term (which is the smallest), and since I spotted $x^4yz$ term with a large coefficient, it is efficient to use that to clean up the $x^2y^2z^2$ mess. This is a really straightforward and common approach to deal with the expanded inequality. There are more advanced techniques for this type of inequality (such as pqr method and HCC) but this problem does not require those.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative proof**:

(pqr method)

Let $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$.

The desired inequality is written as
$$\frac{8}{27} \le \frac{p^3 r - 6pqr + q^3 + 8r^2}{q^3} = \frac{p^3 r - 6pqr + 8r^2}{q^3} + 1. \tag{1}$$

We split into two cases:

<kbd>**Case 1**</kbd> : $p^3 r - 6pqr + 8r^2 \ge 0$

Clearly, (1) is true.

<kbd>**Case 2**</kbd>: $p^3 r - 6pqr + 8r^2 < 0$

Using $q^2 \ge 3pr$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{8}{27} \le \frac{p^3 r - 6pqr + 8r^2}{q \cdot 3pr} + 1$$
or
$$\frac{9p^3 - 35pq + 72 r}{27pq} \ge 0.$$
Using $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}$ (3 degree Schur),
we have
$$9p^3 - 35pq + 72 r
\ge 9p^3 - 35pq + 72\cdot \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}
= p(p^2 - 3q) \ge 0.$$

We are done.

Answer (score 2):

**First solution:** We have

$$8(xy+yz+zx)^3 = [ \sum (xy+yz) ]^3 \leq 9( (xy+yz)^3 +  (yz+zx)^3 + (zx+xy)^3  ), $$

so it remains to show that

$$ (xy+yz)^3 +  (yz+zx)^3 + (zx+xy)^3   \leq 3 (x^2+yz)(y^2+zx)(z^2 + xy). $$

Let $ M (a, b, c) = \sum_{sym} x^a y^b z^c$. Then, by expanding everything, we get that

$$3(x^2+yz)(y^2+zx)(z^2 + xy)  - (xy+yz)^3 -  (yz+zx)^3 - (zx+xy)^3  \\ = M(4, 1, 1) + M(3, 3, 0) + M(2, 2, 2) - M (3, 2, 1). $$

By taking the symmetric summations of $ x^4 yz + x^3y^3 + x^2y^2z^2 \geq 3 x^3 y^2 z$, we get that $ M(4, 1, 1) + M(3, 3, 0) + M(2, 2, 2) \geq 3 M(3, 2, 1)$.
Hence we are done.

---

**Alternative solution:** Continuing from OP's work, WTS

$$27/2 M(4,1,1) + 19/2 M(3, 3, 0) + 1 M(2, 2, 2) \geq 24 M(3, 2, 1).$$

Muirhead tells us that $M(4,1,1) \geq M(3, 2, 1)$ and $M(3, 3, 0) ) \geq M(3, 2, 1)$.
We just need to AM-GM the $M(2, 2, 2)$ term, which has a very small coefficient, so it likely will work out.
As before, by taking the symmetric summations of $ x^4 yz + x^3y^3 + x^2y^2z^2 \geq 3 x^3 y^2 z$, we get that $ M(4, 1, 1) + M(3, 3, 0) + M(2, 2, 2) \geq 3 M(3, 2, 1)$.

Hence (by summing the relevant inequalities), the result follows.

Comment: [+1} Very interesting. Besides, what is the meaning of abbreviation "WTS" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie "Want to Show". This means that I'm still working with the original expression, and am uncertain if it's true. One then has to backtrack in the proof (or ensure that the implications are double-sided).