# Prove $8abc(a+b+c)^3\leq27(a^2+bc)(b^2+ca)(c^2+ab)$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, holder-inequality

Let $a\geq0, b\geq0,c\geq0$. Prove that:

$$8abc(a+b+c)^3\leq27(a^2+bc)(b^2+ca)(c^2+ab).$$

I tried to prove this inequality using only the inequality between the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean.
Does anyone succeed? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try expanding and Muirhead it?

Comment: @CalvinLin Can we use only AM-GM or CS or Holder etc famous inequalities? Something like $(a^2 + bc + bc)(ca + b^2 + ca)(ab + ab + c^2) \ge (\sqrt[3]{a^2caab}+ \sqrt[3]{bc b^2 ab } + \sqrt[3]{bc ca c^2})^3 = abc(a + b + c)^3$.

Comment: @RiverLi I tried a bit but nothing creative stood out to me. The expansion+Muirhead works even without SOS since $(4, 1, 1) + (3, 3, 0) + (2, 2, 2)  \geq 3 ( 3, 2, 1)$ and $(3, 3, 0) \geq (3, 2, 1), (4, 1, 1) \geq (3, 2, 1)$ so I didn't put more effort into it.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks. Muirhead works. Perhaps often we can replace Muirhead by AM-GM for contest inequalities (but it may be longer). Anyway, I am curious if there is a proof without full expanding.

Comment: @CalvinLin I came up with a proof without full expanding. However, I used derivative (calculus). I am curious if there is a proof without calculus.

Comment: By the way, my approach also works for the author's another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4381204/a-typical-inequality-frac827-leq-fracx2yzy2zxz2xyxyyzzx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remark**
$$\displaystyle\sum f(a,b,c)=f(a,b,c)+f(b,c,a)+f(c,a,b)$$
means cyclic sum.
$$\displaystyle\prod f(a,b,c)=f(a,b,c)\cdot f(b,c,a) \cdot f(c,a,b)$$
means cyclic product.

---

denote
$\displaystyle f(a,b,c):=27\prod(a^2+bc)-8abc\sum a$

then expand it, we obtain

$$f(a,b,c)=27\sum{a^3b^3}+19\sum{a^4bc}-24\sum{a^3b^2c}-24\sum{a^2b^3c}+6a^2b^2c^2$$

It's easy to get an SOS form.

$$f(a,b,c)=22 \sum{a^3 b (b-c)^2}+5 \sum{a^3 (b-c)^2 c}+17 \sum{a (a-b)^2 b^2 c}+2 a b c\sum{a (a-b) (a-c)}\geq 0 $$

Comment: (+1) Recently, you provided some SOS solutions. I think you use some solvers.

Comment: @RiverLi haha your comment reminds me of Prof Ji Chen who's famous for all these SOSs with "amazing" coefficients.

Comment: @VezenBU It is amazing since his SOSs are often simple.

Answer (score 1):

**Without full expanding**:

If $abc = 0$, clearly the inequality is true.

In the following, WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c > 0$.

We split into two cases:

**Case 1**: $b^2 \ge ca$

Using Holder, we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{RHS} &\ge 27\left(\sqrt[3]{bc \cdot ca \cdot c^2} + \sqrt[3]{a^2\cdot b^2\cdot ab}\right)^3\\
 &= 27\left(c\sqrt[3]{abc} + ab\right)^3.
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that
$$3(c\sqrt[3]{abc} + ab) \ge 2\sqrt[3]{abc}\,(a + b + c)$$
or
$$3ab \ge \sqrt[3]{abc}\,(2a + 2b - c)$$
which is true. See Remark 1 at the end.

$\phantom{2}$

**Case 2**: $b^2 < ca$

Using Holder, we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{RHS} &\ge 27\left(\sqrt[3]{a^2 \cdot ca \cdot ab} + \sqrt[3]{bc\cdot b^2\cdot c^2}\right)^3\\
 &= 27\left(a\sqrt[3]{abc} + bc\right)^3.
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that
$$3(a\sqrt[3]{abc} + bc) \ge 2\sqrt[3]{abc}(a + b + c)$$
or
$$3bc \ge \sqrt[3]{abc}\,(2b + 2c - a)$$
which is true. See Remark 2 at the end.

We are done.

---

**Remark 1**:

Let $f(c) = \sqrt[3]{abc}\,(2a + 2b - c)$. We have
$f'(c) = \frac{2ab(a + b - 2c)}{3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}} \ge 0$
for all $0 < c \le b^2/a$.

It suffices to prove that
$$3ab \ge \sqrt[3]{ab \cdot \frac{b^2}{a}}\,\left(2a + 2b - \frac{b^2}{a}\right)$$
or
$$a + b^2/a \ge 2b$$
which is true.

**Remark 2**:

Let $g(a) = \sqrt[3]{abc}\,(2b + 2c - a)$. We have
$g'(a) = - \frac{2bc(2a - b - c)}{3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}} \le 0$
for all $a \ge b^2/c$.

It suffices to prove that
$$3bc \ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{b^2}{c} \cdot bc}\,\left(2b + 2c - \frac{b^2}{c}\right)$$
or
$$c + b^2/c \ge 2b$$
which is true.